# How do you make a Node JS Route by Slug not by ID?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a NodeJS blog that works on the MEAN stack (using Express router as well). I do have slugs saved in my MongoDB as strings as well. The end goal I am trying to get is if can call routes using `:slug` instead of `:id`

The current working route that gets my resources by id is:

```
router.get("/resources/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let foundResource = await Resources.findById(req.params.id);
        var metaTitle = foundResource.title;
        var metaDescription = foundResource.description;
        var metaKeywords = foundResource.keywords;
        var metaPath = foundResource.image;
    if (foundResource) {
        let allResources = await Resources.find({});
        res.render("insider/show", { Resources: allResources, resource: foundResource, metaTitle: metaTitle, metaDescription: metaDescription, metaKeywords:metaKeywords, metaPath:metaPath, page_name:'insider'});
    }

});
```

I would like it to be something similar like this:

```
router.get("/resources/:slug", async (req, res) => {
    let foundResource = await Resources.find(req.params.slug);
        var metaTitle = foundResource.title;
        var metaDescription = foundResource.description;
        var metaKeywords = foundResource.keywords;
        var metaPath = foundResource.image;
    if (foundResource) {
        let allResources = await Resources.find({});
        res.render("insider/show", { Resources: allResources, resource: foundResource, metaTitle: metaTitle, metaDescription: metaDescription, metaKeywords:metaKeywords, metaPath:metaPath, page_name:'insider'});
    }
});
```

The model that drives these routes is as follows:

```
// schema setup
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var resourceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,  
    image: String,
    url: String,
    resourceDetails: String,
    price: String,
    category: String,
    value: String,
    excerpt: String,
    slug: String,
    create: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Resources", resourceSchema);
```

Every attempt I have made either gives me a cast error (can't find the ID) or loads the template page without any data in it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using `findById` before, you'd want to replace that with `findOne` - and indicate the field you are looking for.

So replace

`let foundResource = await Resources.find(req.params.slug);`

With

`let foundResource = await Resources.findOne({slug: req.params.slug});`

As a side note - know that mongo automatically indexes `_id`, so if you are changing it to look up `slug`, you'll likely want to index that field for performance.

Comment: This is not working for me. I get the following error: ```CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "123apps" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Resources"```If this is the indexing problem, please advise on how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing in my code referenced the path `_id` so I'm thinking there must be something additional or some changes in your code that are causing this problem. The path you are querying should be `slug`, but this error message indicates you are still querying the `_id` with the slug. The problematic code could look like `findById(slug)` or `findOne({_id: slug})` instead of the correct `findOne({slug: slug})`

Comment: Your code was right. I did not comment out the original route during testing which was what was causing the casting error. Thanks for your help and I am marking this correct now!